# next_auth_providers_google__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ is not a function

Tags: next.js13, next-auth

Running into this issue. Wondering if anyone can help.

9 |   providers: [

> 10 |     GoogleProvider({
> |    ^
> 11 |       clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
> 12 |       clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
> 13 |     }),
> ⨯ src\utils\auth.js (10:4) @ GoogleProvider
> ⨯ TypeError: next_auth_providers_google__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ is not a function

auth.js

```
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const authOptions = {
// adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
providers: \[
GoogleProvider({
clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
}),
// GithubProvider({
//   clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
//   clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
// }),
]
};
```

authprovider.jsx

```
"use client";

import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>
  )
}

export default AuthProvider;
```

src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import { authOptions } from "@/utils/auth";

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

package.json

```
"next": "^13.5.6",
"next-auth": "^4.24.5",
"react": "18.2.0",
```

Thanks!